# Search for posts by title using WP_Query

Tags: wordpress

May I know whether the query below is correct? I would like to search for post that contain the title 'hello' using meta_query with various variables

```
$sq = new WP_Query(array( 'meta_query' => array(array('key' => 'post_title', 'value' => array('%hello%'), 'compare' => 'LIKE')), 'post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => $num, 'post_status' => 'publish', 'order' => $order, 'orderby' => $orderby, 'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1, 'cat' => $cats, 'offset' => $offset));
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`get_page_by_title()` is usually NOT case sensitive. It only would be if the database was set to be case sensitive, which is unusual for MySQL.

Instructions for use of `get_page_by_title()` can be found at: [developer.wordpress.org](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_page_by_title/)

Be sure to set the third parameter if you are wanting posts and not pages.